# Why does creating an Allegro display with a GTK window cause gtk_dialog_run() to segfault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gtk3, allegro5

I am trying to use GTK widgets for certain things in what's mostly an Allegro application.  The following reasonably minimal example results in a segmentation fault during the call to `gtk_dialog_run()`.  However, if the call to `al_create_display()` is removed, then the behaviour is as expected.  Of course, having an Allegro display in an Allegro application is fairly necessary, so this hardly counts as a solution.

Setting the flag `ALLEGRO_GTK_TOPLEVEL` is meant to create the a GTK window at the top-level, and is necessary for using the menu features of Allegro.  I haven't found a way to leverage this - getting a pointer to the `GtkWindow` would allow me to set it as the parent for the dialogue box, for example.  The relevance here is that if this flag is removed, the example again behaves as expected, but this would also preclude using the menu features in Allegro.

I've struggled a bit with getting the debugger to show me the full stack trace - the GTK debug symbols are installed in the package manager but most of the intermediate calls are not visible.  However, the segmentation fault is first reported in `gdk_window_set_geometry_hints()` - which, unfortunately, doesn't return any useful search results when paired with Allegro.

My question is: how can I get GTK widgets to coexist peacefully alongside an Allegro display with a GTK top-level window?

Allegro is version 5.2.4, and GTK is 3.10.8.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_native_dialog.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void show_message_box () {
    // Create the message box
    GtkWidget * message_box = gtk_message_dialog_new (NULL,
                                                      GTK_DIALOG_MODAL,
                                                      GTK_MESSAGE_ERROR,
                                                      GTK_BUTTONS_CLOSE,
                                                      "Hi! It worked.");

    printf ("Entering gtk_dialog_run()\n");
    // This blocks until the user dismisses it
    gtk_dialog_run (GTK_DIALOG (message_box));
    printf ("gtk_dialog_run() returned; dialog should be destroyed.\n");
    // This queues the destruction but does not block
    gtk_widget_destroy (message_box);
    // This satisfies the requests on the queue
    while (gtk_events_pending ()) gtk_main_iteration (); }

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY * display;
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY_MODE disp_data;

    // Allegro initialisation
    if (!(al_init () && al_init_native_dialog_addon ())) {
        printf ("Unable to complete initialisations\n");
        return -1; }

    // Start GTK for dialogs
    if (!gtk_init_check (&argc, &argv)) {
        printf ("Failed to init gtk\n");
        return -1;}

    // Prepare the display
    al_get_display_mode (0, &disp_data);
    al_set_new_display_flags (ALLEGRO_WINDOWED | ALLEGRO_GTK_TOPLEVEL);
    display = al_create_display (512, 512);

    // Announce before and after to illustrate where it breaks
    printf ("Entering show_message_box()\n");
    show_message_box ();
    printf ("Sleeping for 5 seconds; if the dialog still exists something is wrong...\n");

    // The dialog should NOT persist during this sleep
    sleep (5);
    return 0; }
```

Comment: Hello, I'm currently trying to get your code to compile but I have a runtime error from mixing gtk versions somehow. I compiled using pkg-config and allegro_monotlith-debug-5 gtk+-3.0 glib-2.0 and it doesn't work. Could you help me replicate your example with your compilation commands? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. Consider me an interested party. I'd like to investigate why allegro and gtk aren't playing nice together.

Comment: Edit - I linked to gtk+2 only and it worked. Your example shows a dialog box and after closing it sleeps for 5 seconds. I used Allegro 5.2.6 from git and gtk2.

Comment: It looks like allegro links to gtk+2 by default. I can't find a way to configure it to use 3 instead. So your problem may be a matter of linkage.

Comment: I get the same behaviour with GTK+2 only. A minimal compilation command is `gcc test.c -o test $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0) -lallegro -lallegro_dialog`

Comment: You may want to install allegro 5.2.5 or later from get. And by install I mean compile.

Comment: I have Allegro provided via the PPA; the version I currently have installed is indeed 5.2.5.

Comment: I tested Allegro 5.2.5 provided by the ubuntu ppa, GTK 2+, and your program, and it works. So you must have a linking or runtime issue. I can't reproduce your problem. Sorry.

Comment: I can not get GTK-3.0 and Allegro5.0 to work together also. They work on their own, but as each codebase - wants to run off the main thread (I am on a mac) I think there is some conflict.